# What does Ki*Ts mean in Discrete PI controller?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink, matlab-deployment

I am using a Discrete PI controller for an FOC algorithm I am developing in Simulink using the Motor Control Blockset. I would like to use a Ki gain if 2. At the input of the block, I have an input labelled Ki*Ts. If I use my gain with a sampling period of, let's say, 1ms, should Ki*Ts = 2e-3 ? What would be an appropiate sampling period (Ts) and what would be the reason for it ? Please any help would be really appreciated. 
Discrete PI controller Documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/discretepicontroller.html